# Change permission on files in python

Tags: python, unix

I'm trying to do the following:

Write code that checks the permission of each file in the directory 'files'.
If the permission for 'group' is not 'rwx', change the permission of that file 
as follows:
'user' can rwx,
'group' can rwx,
'other' can't do anything.

I have tried the following:

```
import os
import stat

path = '/home/myname/files'
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
  for file in f:
    if not os.access(file, stat.S_IRWXU):
      print("User cannot rwx: ", file)
      os.chmod(file, stat.S_IRWXU)
    if os.access(file, stat.S_IRWXG) == 0:
      print("Group cannot rwx: ", file)
      os.chmod(file, stat.S_IRWXG)
```

However, I am noticing two things.

1. Whatever I try, I can't get it to check if it is NOT rwx. It ignores 'if not', and '== 0' also doesn't work.
2. Calling S_IRWXU changes the permission like I want it to, but when I call 'S_IRWXG' later, the user permission disappears. This is not what I want.
   How do I fix these two things?

Comment: You can't pass `stat.S_IRWXU` to `os.access`. You can only pass a combination of `R_OK`, `W_OK`, and `X_OK`. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.access

Comment: You're better off checking `os.stat` anyway, since you explicitly need to check the group permissions, and `os.access` just checks if the current user has access.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I think you should fix your code:

```
def isGroupRWX(file):
    # check the group bits of the file mode are all set (R, W and X)
    mode = os.stat(file).st_mode
    return (mode and 0b111000) == 0b111000

def fixPermissions(file):
    # set permissions for both user and group to RWX
    os.chmod(file, stat.S_IRWXG or stat.S_IRWXU)
```

You need to check `os.stat` to get the file's mode, since you need to check the group permissions explicitly, not just whether the current user can access the file.

And you can pass a combination of modes to `os.chmod` in order to set them all at the same time, which fixes your second problem.

Comment: Could you explain what's happening in 'isGroupRWX'? How would I apply this myself to for example do the same thing, but instead of looking at 'group' I want to look at 'other'?

Comment: It's getting the file mode as a numeric value, and then masking out the bits that represent the group permissions, and checking that they're all set. If you wanted to check "other", you would change it to `(mode and 0b111) == 0b111`, because the "other" bits are the rightmost (least significant) 3 bits. A decent reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Notation_of_traditional_Unix_permissions - note that the "numeric representation" in that table is in octal, not decimal.